# Visualforce - inputField render as span tag instead of input tag

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, inputfield

I have a visualforce page that displays different fields from the Account object.
One of these fields is the Account Name standard field.

My problem is that this inputField

```
<apex:inputField id="input01" value="{!Account.Name}" />
```

gets rendered as a span tag instead of an input, and user are not able to edit the field.

Please note that this is not a FLS field issue, because field Account.name is editable by default for all profiles.

Do you guys have any idea why this is happening?

Visualforce page rely on the standardController and an extension controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok guys don't mind, the profile was missing the Create permission on the Account object, that's why the Name field was not displaying on the page.

Funny enough, other fields were displaying correctly on the page driving me crazy.

Comment: FYI to anyone reading this, I have this permission but am still receiving this error.